# Display information in UITableView from Firebase based on location Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofencing

I am building an app in Swift and I have a quick question.
When the user enters a certain location, (e.g. shop) I want it to display a list of items saved in Firebase Database in a UITableView (can vary in different locations).
 
I've done a bit of location stuff in Swift before but nothing like this.
Help would be much appreciated!
Thanks so much,
Jake.

```
{
  "venues" : {
    "CrokePark" : {
      "beverages" : {
        "drink1" : "Coca-Cola",
        "drink2" : "Fanta",
        "drink3" : "Dr. Pepper"
      },
      "orders" : {
        "Fanta" : {
          "addedByUser" : "test2@test.com",
          "completed" : false,
          "name" : "Aaron"
        },
        "Coca-Cola" : {
          "addedByUser" : "test@test.com",
          "completed" : false,
          "name" : "Jake"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Show your Database JSON structure

Comment: @Dravidian
{
  "venues" : {
    "CrokePark" : {
      "beverages" : {
        "drink1" : "Coca-Cola",
        "drink2" : "Fanta",
        "drink3" : "Dr. Pepper"
      },
      "orders" : {
        "Fanta" : {
          "addedByUser" : "test2@test.com",
          "completed" : false,
          "name" : "Aaron"
        },
        "Coca-Cola" : {
          "addedByUser" : "test@test.com",
          "completed" : false,
          "name" : "Jake"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Comment: Update your question with your structure

Comment: just updated it

Comment: if you're using geolocation, how come you don't have a node for the stored co-ordinates of these locations?

Comment: I have haven't done much on this kind of development before. I want it so when a user arrives at a certain location (e.g. Croke Park) to display the information within the Croke Park in the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve what you're looking for, you'd generally want to have the exact location i.e. *(latitude, longitude)*, of the cafe stored in your database. So your venue structure would look as such

```
"venues" : {
"CrokePark" : {
  "latitude": 37.335556, // this is a double
  "longitude": -122.009167 // this is a double
  "beverages" : {
    "drink1" : "Coca-Cola",
    "drink2" : "Fanta",
    "drink3" : "Dr. Pepper"
  }
```

With the location you have to worry of retrieval at this point. Generally speaking, you'd want to notify the user when they are a certain radius; *r*, from the venue. Two methods come in mind

**Lousy Battery Draining Method**

Always get an update of their current location, query the database to see if their current location is within *r*. If yes, notify them then stop getting their location and querying Firebase.

This method is the easiest to implement but you sincerely have got to have a serious issue with your users should you opt for it.

**Slightly Improved**

1. Make a *SINGLE* query for the user's current location. Let's call this `let currentLocation = CLLocation2D()`
2. Make a *SINGLE* query to Firebase checking for all locations possibly within *r*; you can even tell FrB to sort them for you, then cache the results. Because of memory limitations you may limit the number of results to say 10. The point is to avoid keeping all the Firebase data in memory at once especially if its going to be massive. Let's call this `let possibleDestinations = []`
3. Start a timer. This is dependent on whether your user is on foot or not. If on foot then a 5-10 minute timer is pretty reasonable. If not then you might want a 1-3 minute timer instead.
4. When `timer == expired` roll back to Step 1

   - Is `currentLocation equal or close to any address in possibleDestinations`

     1. If yes; then our user is definitely headed towards one of the addresses we already have, then `timer.invalidate()` and present the info of the venue from `possibleDestinations`
     2. If no; probably the user has switched their course, then repeat from Step 2

Obviously the second method is more complex than the first one but its more user-friendly; in terms of battery consumption, and efficient.

**Side Note:**

1. I made the `latitude` and `longitude` nodes store `Double` respectively so as you can simply pass them into the `CLLocationDegrees` constructor. More [info](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationdegrees)
2. Since you seem to be relatively new to the Core Location API, I'd recommend you create a side project first and learn how to perform geo-fencing before integrating it into your application. [Current Location Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qrdIL44T6FQ). [Geofencing Tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/136165/core-location-geofencing-tutorial).

Comment: Thank you so much Emil! You're life saver! :)

Comment: @JakeO'Toole Anytime buddy. Oh and uh, side note. When I was working with the geo-fencing stuff I found that running my code in an actual device deemed fruitful than doing it in the simulator.